# Django silent fail on large Response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i'm currently getting started with django and noticed a strange problem, that when a response is too big, it will silently fail and not send any data at all.

i've tested this with a JsonResponse that contains a given set of data in a field, that works perfectly fine.

```
{"data": {
            "hplcdata": {
                "ADC": adcdata,
            }
        }}
```

If i put that same set of data into another field on the same json result, it will fail silently. (Resulting in a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in chrome).

```
    {"data": {
            "hplcdata": {
                "ADC": adcdata,
                "ADC2": adcdata,
            }
        }}
```

i've also tested this with a self-implemented JsonResponse type that consists of a view with a single variable that will be set and safe-mode disabled, resulting in the same empty response.

The Log in the first case looks like this:

> Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8088/
>
> Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>
> [10/Mar/2017 15:38:27] "GET /api/HplcData/3/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 302714

In the second case it looks like this:

> Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8088/
>
> Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>
> [10/Mar/2017 15:39:47] "GET /api/HplcData/3/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 605415

It does not seem to be a browser issue either, since firefox responds in the same way.

At first i thought it was a graphql problem (which i tried to utilize before), but now that i am using the same data and i can see my code executing just fine until it returns the response, i guess there is a problem somewhere in the framework.

Runtime: Python 3.6

Libraries currently in use (based on requirements.txt):

- pyserial==3.2.1
- django==1.10.5
- graphene-django==1.2.1
- django-graphiql==0.4.4
- Flask-GraphQL==1.4.1
- django-filter==1.0.1

i already searched in the documentation if there is a maximum response size, but there doesn't seem to be anything like this.

i've also just tested version 1.10.6, which resulted in the same behaviour

Has anyone experience a similar issue and could tell me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

And just what you expect it to be: use the latest version (1.11b1 at the time of writing) and it will work correctly.

sadly, graphene-filter doesn't seem to be compatible with that version as of yet

at least i can go into the weekend now